# Scrollview with uiview on top

Tags: ios7, uiscrollview

I have scrollview and on top of it there is a uiview, what I want to do is when i scroll scrollview then top uiview should also get scrolled accordingly. I don't want to put that uiview inside the scrollview due to some reason . but how to make it scrollable even though it is not inside the scrollview.

Answer (score 0):

If you want another view to scroll, it should also be a UIScrollView or a class which inherits it. The UIView itself is not scrollable.

Thus, you could link you background scroll view contentOffset to your front scroll view.

Anyways, your restrictions are strange. If you could be more explicit, someone might provide you a more usefull/simple method to achieve your tasks.

Comment: Yaah even i tried with a scrollview inside a scrollview.. but how will i get to know which scrollview is being scrolled.. if both the scrollview are vertically scrollable. the outer scrollview will contain a uiview on top and a scrollview. what was happening was sometimes inside scrollview was getting scrolled sometimes the outside one..

Comment: Scrollview inside a scrollview is kinda wrong. You also said that the view you want to scroll, is not a subview of the scrollview.

Comment: I have used uiview on top of scrollview.. in scrollviewdidscroll i am changing the frame  position of uiview as per the change in content offset of scrollview.. when i scroll slowly it works fine.. but for faster scrolling.. it doesn't work so.. may be the scrollviewdidscroll is not getting called for every pixel change.. suggest me how to make it work even if user scroll's faster.

Answer (score 0):

You can listen to the scrollView's `contentOffset` with KVO, and update your upper UIView's `transform` accordingly.